# MacBook Pro (2007 - ATI-Card) Screen goes half black then shuts down the entire computer

Tags: macbook, display, shutdown, macbook-pro

when I'm starting my MBP I get about 10-60 seconds of the booting process before the screen goes half black (Its like applying a black to transparent gradient from the left side of the screen to the middle of the screen). After a 5 seconds the entire screen blacks out and the MBP shuts down.

There have been issues with heat and some minor artifacts on the screen in the past but nothing serious as far as I know. Everything could be resolved by rebooting or letting the MBP cool down a bit.

I would like to identify the problem now. There are 3 possibilities I can think of right now:

1. My graphics card is defect and shuts down after a few seconds. (But if thats true, I find it kind of hard to explain the HALF black screen)
2. My LCD-Panel is defect and sends back wrong signals so the system shuts down??? (I not sure about that)
3. My fan or/and thermal sensors are defect and forcing the graphics card to shut down.

Can anyone point if I'm right or if there yet another reason for this.

I'd be thankful for any hint or tips.

Cheers,
Per

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, there have not been any 2007 MacBook Pros manufactured with ATI cards; yours is a 2006 model. I see some reports of failed GPUs in that family reported on the Apple forums.

I would try to [reset the PRAM/NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) for starters and see if it helps, but it does indeed sound like a GPU failure. The cost of replacing it is upstream of $500 at Apple, because you'd need a logic board replacement as well.

Comment: I've done the resetting already. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: Ehm yeah, and I'm currently trying to figure out if I can avoid a new logic board. But thanks anyway. Your comments are just confirming my best guess on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pretty spot on with the graphic card defect, I've seem some weird stuff from defective video cards.

A long shot might also be a inadequate amount of power being supplied to the GPU due to a faulty Power supply.

I don't know a ton about MACS but I thought you could just take them in to the MAC store and get them fixed for free with their uber warranty?

Comment: Faulty power supply you say. Is there an easy way to test that? I guess not!? And I don't think there is any warranty left after 4-5 years. But Thx

Answer (score 0):

The gradient grey makes me think the LCD is bad (or a cracked/shorted LVDS cable).

The hard shut-down is a solid indicator that you've got a serious hardware issue.

i would try starting in safe mode (boot and hold the SHIFT key until you've got the apple and the "grey grinding wheel")....

IF the unit will boot in safe mode then its MORE LIKELY the GPU chip (logic board) than the LCD.

Either way, (LCD or logic board), I'd not put any money into this system - it's well beyond its prime and I'd very heartily recommend an upgrade.. The logic boards are known for failure...

There is NO separate "power supply" in this era system - if it's got a power system issue, it would be on board the logic board, in which case you need to say a prayer and bury it.